# Is there an add-in for Microsoft Outlook that guesses the folder for filing emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, plugins

Is there an add-in for Microsoft Outlook that will assist in filing emails in folders by guessing the folder that an email should go in?  The software on my blackberry does this, guessing with great accuracy, I assume based on some text analysis of the sender and the subject line.  It would be helpful to have the same functionality in Outlook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My favorite is [SimplyFile](http://www.techhit.com/SimplyFile/)

Answer (score 2):

[SpeedFiler](http://www.claritude.com/)

Comment: Looks helpful, but it requires that you give it part of the folder name.  Blackberry has some algorithm to guess the correct folder itself.

Comment: You start by telling it where to file the emails and then it learns as you go along. It selects the correct folder for about 90% of my emails and maybe 1-2% it gets wrong and it doesn't provide a guess for the remainder.

Comment: +1 for SpeedFiler. Also very handy for quickly navigating to different folders in Outlook.

Comment: Do you know if this can be installed without administrative rights?

Comment: Given that it has to install itself as a Microsoft Outlook addin. I would say it requires admin rights. The supplied setup program certainly does.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Outclass](http://www.vargonsoft.com/Outclass/default.aspx?version=1.2.4.1r)?

I searched for something that uses Bayesian filtering to sort into N buckets instead of just two buckets: Spam/Ham (non-spam). The Bayesian algorithm requires some training at first, but it seems to be very accurate (over 99.X%). This accuracy may go down as you add more buckets (I'm not sure)...

This [discussion](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.105701.11) from The Joel on Software Discussion Group led me to Outclass. I haven't used it myself, and it seems to only support POP (no IMAP)

Comment: Argh, people implementing my ideas before I get a chance too :()